# Do C standards specify how far the carry propagates when incrementing a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

Consider the following situations:

- The [National Semiconductor SC/MP](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/why-were-the-sc-mp-pointers-12-bit-kinda) has pointers which, when you keep incrementing them, will roll from 0x0FFF to 0x0000 because the increment circuit does not propagate the carry past the lower nybble of the higher byte. So if, for example, I want to do `while(*ptr++)` to traverse a null-terminated string, then I might wind up with `ptr` pointing outside of the array.
- On the [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10), because a machine word is longer than an address<sup>1</sup>, a pointer may have tags and other data in the upper half of the word containing the address. In this situation, if incrementing a pointer causes an overflow, that other data might get altered. The same goes for very early Macintoshes, before the ROMs were 32-bit clean.

So my question is about whether the C standard says what incrementing a pointer really means. As far as I can tell, the C standard assumes that it should work in bit-wise the same manner as incrementing an integer. But that doesn't always hold, as we have seen.

**Can a standards-conforming C compiler emit a simple `adda a0, 1`<sup>2</sup> to increment a pointer, without checking that the presence or lack of carry propagation will not lead to weirdness?**

---

1: On the PDP-10, an address is 18 bits wide, but a machine word is 36 bits wide. A machine word may hold either two pointers (handy for Lisp) or one pointer, plus bitfields which mean things like "add another level of indirection", segments, offsets etc. Or a machine word may of course contain no pointers, but that's not relevant to this question.

2: Add one to an address. That's 68000 assembler.

Comment: C standard specifies that pointer arithmetic which is resulting in a pointer pointing outside a valid object (or one object past it) has an undefined behavior. Pretty much covering your question.

Comment: In a nutshell: Pointer arithmetic only has defined behaviour when applied to values that are the addresses of objects. No such addresses exist where the situation of the question could apply. (E.g. on x86, the compiler would not be allowed to allocate a `char` at the maximal address, since you wouldn't be able to form the one-past-the-end pointer.)

Comment: In a similar vein, I have a vague memory that a large pointer from the 8086 real mode days would not increment correctly at: XXXX:FFFF.  The reason my memory is a little vague at this point is that I haven't touched such a beast in over twenty years. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People often ask, "Why does C have undefined behavior, anyway?".  And this is a great example of one of the big reasons why.

Let's stick with the NS SC/MP example.  If the hardware dictates that incrementing the pointer value `0x0FFF` doesn't work quite right, we have two choices:

1. Translate the code `p++` to the equivalent of `if(p == 0x0FFF) p = 0x1000; else p++;`.
2. Translate `p++` to a straight increment, but rig things up so that no properly-allocated object ever overlaps an address involving `0x0FFF`, such that if anyone ever writes code that ends up manipulating the pointer value `0x0FFF` and adding one to it and getting a bizarre answer, you can say "that's undefined, so anything can happen".

If you take approach #1, the generated code is bigger and slower.  If you take approach #2, the generated code is maximally efficient.  And if someone complains about the bizarre behavior, asks why the compiler couldn't have emitted code that did something "more reasonable", you can simply say, "our mandate was to be as efficient as possible."

Comment: @Wilson I mean whatever it takes -- but yes, it might very well involve `ld`.  Certainly `ld` and libc are part of the C implementation.  Another example is that `ld` must take care not to put any object at address 0, if that would cause its address to look like a null pointer.

Comment: @Wilson: The C library would be part of a hosted C implementation.  Freestanding implementations aren't required to supply any library functions other than those that the compiler itself might use for complicated operations like floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 14):

Behavior of pointer arithmetic is specified by the C standard only as long as the result points to a valid object or just past a valid object. More than that, the standard does not say what the bits of a pointer look like; an implementation may arrange them to suit its own purposes.

So, no, the standard does not say what happens when a pointer is incremented so far that the address rolls over.

If the `while` loop you refer to only proceeds one element past the end of the array, it is safe in C. (Per the standard, if `ptr` has been incremented to one element beyond the end of the array, and `x` points to any element in the array, including the first, then `x < ptr` must be true. So, if `ptr` has rolled over internally, the C implementation is responsible for ensuring the comparison still works.)

If your `while` loop may increment `ptr` more than one element beyond the end of the array, the C standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: The pointer is valid when pointing just past the valid range (so pointer arithmetic is valid), but dereferencing it is not.

Comment: It is probably not possible to provide correct behaviour on pointer arithmetic overflow. I believe most implementations just avoid allocating the last byte in the address space if the end of the address space is usable.

Comment: So if a pointer cannot increment past some address which is _not_ the end of the address space, as on the SC/MP, then the implementation needs to avoid letting arrays and such straddle that address in order to be standards compliant right? That means `malloc` and `strcpy` and so on need to be written particularly for that target?

Comment: @wilson: it doesn't matter to strcpy, since malloc will ensure that no object straddles segments. And, yes, malloc needs to know a lot about the target; you cannot write  a non-trivial malloc portably. The compiler/linker also need to ensure static and automatic objects don't straddle.

Comment: @rici: Of course it is possible. Another solution is not to support any object (even aggregates) whose size exceeds 0x7ff bytes. Then any two pointers may be compared by subtracting the latter from the former. If the 0x800 bit is on in the result, the latter is later in the object than the former, regardless of whether the object straddles the wrap. I would not necessarily recommend such an implementation, but many things are possible.

Comment: @rici: It's possible to write a malloc() which is portable to high-quality implementations that's designed to support low-level programming constructs on linear-addressing platforms.  Simply create a union with a `char[REQUIRED_HEAP_SIZE]` and a `struct` containing a `char` and a union of every primitive type; have `malloc` carve space out of the `char[]`, and use the union's offset to determine alignment.  Platforms with non-linear addressing will require special treatment, but that doesn't mean most platforms would require individually-targeted `malloc` implementations.

Comment: @supercat: I was thinking of mentioning that possibility, but it seemed sufficiently limited that I didn't bother. I don't think it fits into the category of "non-trivial" because it isn't really dynamic: it requires you to know in advance how much heap you will require. That's inevitable with a portable solution since the C standard provides no way of accessing, modifying or querying the heap other than malloc itself (and friends). Even Posix removed sbrk. But, sure, your strategy will work fine. I won't argue it.

Comment: @rici: Being able to have `malloc` automatically size itself to available storage is sometimes a useful feature, but the reverse can always be true.  Acquiring storage for `malloc` at load time may ensure that trying to run a program with insufficient memory will result in immediate rather than delayed failure.  It may also be helpful in cases where it would be better for a program's `malloc()` attempts to fail than to have it take acquire so much system memory that other tasks get starved.  My main point, though, is that "malloc" isn't as "magical" as some people think.

Answer (score 1):

A significant number of platforms have addressing methods which cannot index "easily" across certain boundaries.  The C Standard allows implementations two general approaches for handling this (which may be, but typically aren't, used together):

1. Refrain from having the compiler, linker, or `malloc`-style functions place any objects in a way that would straddle any problematic boundaries.
2. Perform address computations in a way that can index across arbitrary boundaries, even when it would be less efficient than address-computation code that can't.

In most cases, approach #1 will lead to code which is faster and more compact, but code may be limited in its ability to use memory effectively.  For example, if code needs many objects of 33,000 bytes each, a machine with 4MiB of heap space subdivided into "rigid" 64K chunks, would be limited to creating 64 of them (one for each chunk), even though there should be space for 127 of them.  Approach #2 will often yield much slower code, but such code may be able to make more effective use of heap space.

Interestingly, imposing 16-bit or 32-bit alignment requirements would allow many 8-bit processors to generate more efficient code than allowing arbitrary alignment (since they could omit page-crossing logic when indexing between the bytes of a word) but I've never seen any 8-bit compilers provide an option to impose and exploit such alignments even on platforms where it could offer considerable advantages.

Answer (score 0):

C standard does not know anything about the implementation, and the standard does not care about the implementation. It only says what the effect of the pointer arithmetics is.

C allows something which is called Undefined Behavior. C does not care if the result of the pointer arithmetic has any sense (ie it is not out of bounds or the actual implementation defined storage did not wrap around). If it happens it is the UB. It is up to programmer to prevent UB, and C does not have any standard mechanisms for detecting or preventing UB.